# Puzzled with mysql ERROR 1064 (42000)

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using  5.5.46 server on Debian.

I'm wondering what's wrong with the following syntax, I'm getting the following error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 5: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near 'desc  VARCHAR(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
>       hora  VARCHAR(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,    ' at line 3

```
drop database loteria;
create database loteria;
use loteria;

create table loteria (
    id    SMALLINT(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    desc  VARCHAR(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    hora  VARCHAR(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    primary key(id)
);
```

I can't see the error, can you please guide me to identify it.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: desc is a reserved word

Answer (score 2):

`varchar` types CANNOT be "`UNSIGNED`".  They are alphanumeric types--`UNSIGNED` does not apply. Also, `desc` is a reserved word.

The below will work, back-ticking the column names. Note that only `desc` needs to be back-ticked because it is a *Reserved Word*. But, it is common practice to back-tick them all for safety sake. A space or a hyphen in a column name can trigger a similar syntax error.

```
create table `loteria` (
    `id`    SMALLINT(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `desc`  VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    `hora`  VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    primary key(`id`)
);
```

For a list of reserved words in mysql, see [This Link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html) and they are the ones with an (R) next to their name.

Comment: That was stupid. Thanks. I had over 5 years didn't do anything with SQL. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems: `desc` is a reserved word which cannot be used as a column name, and `varchar` cannot be "unsigned", since it's a character string type.